# How to add Column to DataFrame while keeping dates correlated

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas and Matplotlib to chart some Crypto Transactions.

The column I am working with is `Amount`, where I am trying to chart the incoming and outgoing transactions. Incoming has `a +` in front of the number, and outgoing has `a -`.

The goal is to use Matplotlib to create a bar chart with the incoming and outgoing transactions.

What I think needs to be done is for the `Amount` column to be sorted by if it contains `a +` or `a -`, and then each type have their own column that is correlated with the date of the transaction.

For example, the +20,000 Transaction on the first row would be filed under the `Incoming Transactions` column, while on the same row that it was originally in (to keep the same date).

I have attempted to create this but based on my error code I am having trouble when it comes to creating a new column.

```
parse_dates = ['Time']
df = pd.read_csv('DSb5CvAXhXnzFoxmiMaWpgxjDF6CfMK7h2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=parse_dates)

df2 = df.assign(Outgoing = df.loc[df["Amount"].str.contains('\-', regex=True)]) 

#outgoing_transactions = df.loc[df["Amount"].str.contains('\-', regex=True)]

#incoming_transactions = df.loc[df["Amount"].str.contains('\+', regex=True)]

df2
```

This is the error code I receive:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) from the `Amount` column only the value relative to the Dogecoin. Then, create a variable to indicate the transaction's direction and use it with accessor `.dt.date` to create the groups.

Use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) `sum` to add values within the same day and transaction type, follow by [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to pivot the transaction type into two different columns. Use the columns created to plot the data using two different [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) commands, this will give the effect of two bars on the same day, one for each transaction type.

**df** used as input

```py
                            Time                              Amount
0  2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  +7,965,429.87 DOGE (18,343.48 USD)
1  2022-01-01 07:30:54.545454545  -5,986,584.84 DOGE (15,601.86 USD)
2  2022-01-01 15:01:49.090909090    +999,749.16 DOGE (45,924.89 USD)
3  2022-01-01 22:32:43.636363636  +6,011,150.12 DOGE (70,807.26 USD)
4  2022-01-02 06:03:38.181818181    -564,115.79 DOGE (72,199.88 USD)
..                           ...                                 ...
95 2022-01-30 17:56:21.818181818  -6,454,722.96 DOGE (17,711.07 USD)
96 2022-01-31 01:27:16.363636363  -4,699,445.14 DOGE (27,956.03 USD)
97 2022-01-31 08:58:10.909090909    -3,701,587.0 DOGE (1,545.66 USD)
98 2022-01-31 16:29:05.454545454   -3,307,503.05 DOGE (55,276.5 USD)
99 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000000  +9,636,199.77 DOGE (85,300.95 USD)

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

```py
df['DOGE'] = df['Amount'] \
    .str.extract(r'([+-](?:\d+,?)+?(?:.\d+)?)\s') \
    .replace(",","", regex=True).astype(float)

flow = df['DOGE'].apply(lambda x: "outcome" if x<0 else "income")

grouped = df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.date, flow])
action = grouped.agg(amount=('DOGE', sum)).unstack()

if ('amount','income') in action:
    plt.bar(action.index, action[('amount', 'income')], color='g', label='income')
if ('amount', 'outcome') in action:
    plt.bar(action.index, action[('amount', 'outcome')], color='r', label='outcome')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: income_outcome_barplot]